# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() WAMP 2.2e to SQL 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, wampserver

OK so I have a WAMP 2.2e (on a Windows 7 Machine) install running perfectly. However I am trying to connect to my SQL 2005 (Server 2003 OS) server but am getting the above error in PHP. I have already grabbed the correct PHP drivers and they are active in the PHP.ini file and in the correct ext folder. I have been going around in circles with what I have been finding online. Someone please help!

```
$serverName = "NAME"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBNAME", "UID"=>"USER", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

and I get: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Comment: This question has been asked here before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953053/call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-when-trying-to-connect-to-azure-db

Comment: This is for an Azure DB. and I already grabbed the SQL drivers with no luck still.